# ¿Los arrays también se heredan? (JAVA)

Tags: java, array, poo, herencia

Quizás es algo tonta mi pregunta pero es que soy algo nuevo en la programación.
Estoy intentado hacer una agenda en java donde los contactos sean alojados en los arrays. Éstos los creé en la clase padre y asigné sus valores en una clase hija pero en dicha clase no me los reconoce. ¿A qué se debe esto?. Adjunto el código debajo, cualquier tipo de ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias!

```
public class ClasePadre {

Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
protected String nombre, apellido;
protected long numero;
String Nombre[] = new String[99];
String Apellido[] = new String[99];
long Numero[] = new long[99];

public void NuevoContactoMenu() {

    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Apellido: ");
    apellido = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Numero telefonico: ");
    numero = entrada.nextLong();
}
```

Éste método pertenece a la clase hija

```
public void Crear() {
    int i = 0, x = 0;

    System.out.println("------- CREAR CONTACTO -------");

    do {
        NuevoContactoMenu();    

        Nombre[i] = nombre;     
        Apellido[i] = apellido;
        Numero[i] = numero;
        i++;                    

        System.out.println("Contacto creado!");
        System.out.println("1. Crear otro contacto");
        System.out.println("2. Salir");

        x = entrada.nextInt();
    } while (x != 2); 
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías añadir el código de las clases que mencionas? En cualquier caso para que una clase hija pueda acceder a un atributo de una clase padre, el atributo tiene que ser o `public` o `protected`. El que sea un array no interfiere en esto, es decir que los arrays se heredan igual que cualquier otro tipo de atributo.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida! Disculpa mi ignorancia, ¿cómo te lo podría adjuntar? Ya que por acá me excedería en caracteres y editando la publicación me aparece que ésta es mayormente código

Comment: Si, me refería a que editases la misma pregunta que has hecho y que incluyas en modo texto el código que tengas. No hace falta todo todo el código, pero si lo que veas que es importante. Por ejemplo aqui interesaria ver como se definen la clase padre e hijo que mencionas y como se define el atributo que resulta ser es un array para ver si es protected, public o private.

Comment: La solución es básicamente que les pongas `protected` por delante vaya, pero así vemos cual es exactamente el problema sin hacer suposiciones. Ejemplo: `protected String Nombre = new String[99];`

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias, creía que al dejar el modificador default igualmente podría acceder a ellos ya que ambas clases pertenecen al mismo paquete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Éstos los creé en la clase padre y asigné sus valores en una clase hija pero en dicha clase no me los reconoce"

Para acceder a los valores de una clase diferente debes especificar la clase (en caso de que las propiedades sean estaticas), junto con el nombre de la propiedad o metodo al que quieras acceder, ademas recuerda que para poder que una propiedad o metodo sea accesible desde otra clase deberas declarar las `propiedades` y `metodos` que desees que puedan ser usados en la segunda clase como `public` o `protected`, por ejemplo, si tienes un propiedad llamada `nombre` en tu clase `ClasePadre` y quieres usarla en otra clase o si tienes un metodo llamado `llamar` en tu clase padre y también quieres poder usarlo en la clase hijo o algun otra clase deberás usar:

```
System.out.println(ClasePadre.nombre);
ClasePadre.llamar();
```

Por supuesto teniendo en cuenta que esa es la forma de acceder propiedades y metodos **estaticos**, si intentas usar esa forma de acceder a las propiedades sin que la propiedad o el metodo a acceder sea **estatico** te dará un error, para clarificar un poco mas esto aquello que esta arriba lo puedes ver de la siguiente manera aquí:

```
class ClasePadre{
   public static nombre = "Juan";

   public static void llamar(){
      System.out.println("llamando a : " + this.nombre);
   }

}
```

Pero y que pasa con aquellas propiedades que no sean estaticas??, como las accedemos??

Para aquellas propiedades o metodos que no sean declarados como estaticos solo puedes accederlos mediante la instancia de la clase, es decir, apartir de un objeto `ClasePadre`, por lo cual se hace necesario que previamente crees un objeto de ese tipo para poder usar sus `metodos` o `propiedades` de la siguiente manera:

```
class ClaseNoPrincipal{

   public nombre = "Juan";

   public void llamar(){
      System.out.println("llamando a: " + this.nombre);
   }

   //Constructor de la clase
   void ClaseNoPrincipal(){}

}
```

Teniendo esa clase, vemos que **no existe** el `modificador static` ni en la propiedad `nombre` ni en el metodo `llamar`, por lo que asumamos que tienes otra clase en la que quieres usar la informacion de esa clase, entonces dentro de esa clase debes crear primero una `instancia` de la clase `ClaseNoPrincipal` para luego poder usar tanto las propiedades como sus metodos al no ser estas propiedades o metodos declarados como `static`, entonces en esta otra clase podemos usar tanto la propiedad `nombre` como el metodo `llamar` de la clase `ClaseNoPrincipal` de la siguiente manera:

```
class Main{

   //Declaramos como static puesto que el metodo main es static y nos obliga
   //A hacerlo.
   public static ClaseNoPrincipal claseNoPrincipal;

   public static void main(String[] args){

      //Creamos la instancia asignandole un `new ClaseNoPrincipal`
      Main.claseNoPrincipal = new ClaseNoPrincipal();

      //Ahora podemos usar la informacion y metodos de Main.claseNoPrincipal:
      System.out.println(Main.claseNoPrincipal.nombre);
      Main.claseNoPrincipal.llamar();

   }

}
```

Es necesario aclarar que el motivo de crear una clase llamada `ClaseNoPrincipal` en vez de simplemente ponerle cualquier otro nombre mas normal, es porque queria recalcar que se esta usando una clase que `NO` es la principal, puesto a que hay que tener en cuenta que la clase principal arranca sola y no puede y no debe ser instanciada.

Ademas declaramos la variable `claseNoPrincipal` como `static`, haciendo que automaticamente ahora podamos acceder desde cualquier otra clase a esa propiedad usando el formato: `clase.propiedad`, que en nuestro ejemplo seria equivalente a `Main.claseNoPrincipal`, notese que `claseNoPrincipal` esta en minusculas, por lo cual nos referimos a la instancia de la clase y **NO** a la clase en si.

Al principio todo esto puede parecerte un poco confuso y dificil de entender, pero pues asi es java y asi funciona...

Sin embargo hay que aclarar algo:

**Estas confundiendo que es heredar o extender y como se comportan.**

Hablar de si se puede extender un `Array` si tiene sentido puesto que enrealidad si se pueden extender, pero solo algunos en particular... por ejemplo arreglos genericos (me gusta llamarles asi) como el mixin entre `Map` y `HashMap` o `ArrayList`, esto debido a que **2** de esos **tres** anteriormente mencionados **no son tipos primitivos**, son `clases` y por lo cual se pueden extender de estos para heredar todas las propiedades y metodos de ellos en otra clase.

Sin embargo para arreglos comunes primitivos con memoria fija como:

```
String[] nombres = new String[8];
```

**No** es posible este comportamiento, puesto que los `arreglos comunes` que nosotros conocemos son considerados como un mixin entre `primitivo` y `generico`, siendo el contenedor de estos (el array en si), un tipo primitivo y los tipos alojados ya sea `genericos` o `primitivos`, por lo cual no se puede extender de un array normal.

Para resumirlo un poco de manera un poco abrupta y fea, podemos decir que **cualquier cosa que sea una clase puede ser extendida o heredada**, mas **no necesariamente cualquier clase puede ser instanciable**.

Por lo que tu confusion es enrealidad pensar que cuando tu creas una nueva clase, esta automaticamente hereda todas las propiedades y metodos de las otras, haciendo que puedas usarlos directamente, lo cual **NO es para nada así**.

Lo que enrealidad ocurre es que cada clase tiene su `"entorno"`, este entorno es comunmente llamado `scope`, y para poder acceder a las clases o sus metodos hay una manera especifica de hacerlo.

**Las propiedades o metodos de una clase no son heredados directamente a no ser de que tu se lo indiques a la clase**.

Esto significa que enrealidad como comportamiento predeterminado ninguna de tus clases hereda directamente de otra, por lo cual **lo que hace parte de una clase, se queda en esa clase**, y enrealidad **NO** necesitas hacerlo para tu caso, no necesitas complicarte extendiendo cosas por ahora, puesto que hay dos opciones, que anteriormente ya te he mencionado (`modificador static` o crear una instancia de la clase que desees usar en la otra).

Todo esto para no tener que `extender` de la otra clase puesto que al `extender` a la otra clase y llamar a `super` no solo heredarias las propiedades de la clase padre, si no que ademas `copiarias sus metodos`, lo cual en ciertos casos no es lo deseado...

Todo dependera de que es lo que deseas...

Por ejemplo cuando deseas crear objetos generales (ordenador), y descomponerlo en partes mas pequenas (perifericos), que deriven de algo mas grande, funcionaria bien el hacer herencia a una clase padre (ordenador), para crear una clase mas especifica (periferico).

Una cosa mas a tener en cuenta es que pese a que el modificador `static` parece muy poderoso y conveniente, no es ideal el usarlo, de hecho se aconseja muchas vecez usarlo lo menos posible, no recuerdo exactamente el porque de ello (segun eso genera problemas y reduce la eficiencia del programa), por lo que siempre que puedas evita usar `static`, y usalo solo cuando no se te ocurre otra opcion.

**Esto no aplica para los metodos, para los metodos es buena idea usar el modificador static a fin de crear clases de utilidad**

Recuerda que la alternativa a usar `static` es simplemente crear instancias de `clases` (un objeto), con el cual puedes usar sus propiedades o metodos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven! Tu comentario fue de utilidad no sólo para resolver mi problema sino también para aclararme otras dudas a aparte que tenía!

Answer (score 1):

Las propiedades a las que se intenta acceder son default (sin modificador) por lo que no son accesibles desde subclases:

```
Access Levels
-------------
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------
public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N <----     N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

La solución es hacer los atributos o public o protected (recomendablemente protected a ser posible).

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html